# how to limiting word on the laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I'm looking to find out how to limit word in laravel blade. I've coded using substr, but it's still not working properly. Can anyone help me?

```
<div class="description">
   {{ substr($UseCase->translate($lang)->description, 20).'...' }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Str::words` method limits the number of words in a string. An additional string may be passed to this method via its third argument to specify which string should be appended to the end of the truncated string:

```
{{Str::words($UseCase->translate($lang)->description, 20, ' (...)')}}
```

you have to import

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-words

you can avoid use import like below

```
 {{\Illuminate\Support\Str::words($UseCase->translate($lang)->description, 20, ' (...)')}}
```

Comment: Can I change it only in the blade template? Because I don't want to disturb the backend staff code

Comment: you can change in blade or controller or in model as you like